# Why do some websites/applications require that passwords must begin with a letter?

Tags: security, passwords, requirements

Some number of websites/applications require that a password must begin with a letter, I find this plain stupid. It's pretty annoying... and the password entropy (security) is greatly reduced.
So my question is... Is there a reason why some developers would choose this?

The only reasons I could think of are:

- They are sheep (Seen it required somewhere else and just copied the trend)
- Some just implement it because that's the little regex they know
- Just to create a false sense of security for their clients

(Asking because I'm developing an app to manage user passwords and thinking to alert the users that if the website asks for that, they should not trust their security)

Comment: That particular requirement annoys me too, in particular because it narrows the set of possible matches without incenting the user to come up with something less predictable than average.  The "minimum size of 8, letters in both cases and numbers" constraint seems to me to provide a good balance between providing that user incentive and not narrowing the set of matches too much.  I still prefer the "weak medium strong" feedback approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding security there is no reason such a password requirement makes sense, you already gave the answer yourself. I do not think that giving out a warning is necessary though, because the implementation is not necessarily an unsecure one.

In my opinion the only reasonable restriction for passwords is a minimum length. Other requirements can interfere with good password schemes and can actually reduce the strength of passwords, because users will switch to weaker passwords like "Password2014".

Comment: The implementation is insecure because it reduces password entropy. I strongly agree that users will switch to weaker passwords when their choices are limited, because their first concern about passwords is to easily remember them. So adding an extra requirement that weakens the password, has no use from what i see and pushes the user to choose a weaker password because it limits his choices is definitely a strong clue about how the whole application/website is designed considering that the developer made such a poor choice when designing the password requirements.

Comment: @hi-XBOty - This is my opinion too, and the mentioned restriction is really not useful. On the other side, there are so many restrictions which are recommended in so many places, that it's easy to think they _are_ important. Even a developer who did some research, could think he has to implement such restrictions, or maybe the boss has demanded it.

Comment: @hi-XBOty While I also strongly agree that users will switch to weaker passwords when their choices are limited up to a point, I must also observe that they will switch to even weaker ones when their choices are unlimited, for the reason you mention.